# Is it necessary to have an inverse relation in CoreData

Tags: core-data

I have an existing Core Data entity in the production version of my app. I want to add a new entity that has a relation to the previous one but I read that you need to have an inverse relation as well. If I do this, will the data stored on devices that use the previous entity be erased? And can I get away with not having an inverse relationship?

Comment: You don't need an inverse relationship but it is recommended. Nothing will be erased and I assume the inverse relationship will be optional anyway since no objects exists for the new entity.

Answer (score 2):

While it's technically possible to not configure a inverse relationship in CoreData, it is recommended to do so as written in one of Apple's articles about [configuring relationships](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/modeling_data/configuring_relationships#):

> Inverse relationships enable Core Data to propagate change in both directions when an instance of either the source or destination type changes. **Every relationship must have an inverse.**

Answer (score 2):

If you just add the inverse to **existing** relationship, without creating a migrator to update everything, yes, the records will be erased. (Ask me how I know... OK, I'll tell you. I did this and caused a major prod incident my first month at my new job...)

However, if you are adding a brand new relationship along with an inverse, that should be fine. You can use a lightweight migrator since you're just adding properties and relationships. The issue only comes up if you had a non-inverse relationship, and then try to add an inverse.

I highly recommend adding the inverse when you add the relationship. You'll get warnings if you don't that are very hard to remove later (as discussed above).

Comment: So I create a new version of the current entity and add the inverse relationship to the relationship I'm going to create, all using the migration process, that's the right way to go ahead, correct?

Comment: Yeah. You'll need a heavy-weight migrator (i.e. write code) to actually wire-up the inverse.